# Using ADAL from a trusted subsystem to call an RBAC'd Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, adal, rbac

**MVC Client:**

During app start-up, my WebApp “client” loads up a cache of data mostly used for driving certain menus that are common to all users.
So, the app would call the API as a “trusted subsystem” .. not on behalf of any particular user.

I'm sure my answer lies in [this Azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity) ...

I think this is a case where, in my web app, when I start to grab a token, I want to do one of the following:

```
 AuthenticationResult result = 
    await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(tslResourceID, clientcred, 
                                              UserIdentifier.AnyUser);
```

Or omit the UserIdentifier parameter altogether?

```
 AuthenticationResult result = 
    await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(tslResourceID, clientcred);
```

I think the sample does it like the latter, as shown in [their ToDoListController](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/Controllers/TodoListController.cs#L92-L96)

---

**Protected Resource:**

Now, my Web API is protected with RBAC, do I need to modify the [Authorize] attribute further?

```
public class LocationsController : ODataController
{
    private MyDbModel db = new MyDbModel();

    [EnableQuery]
    [Authorize(Roles = "AdminAccess,FullAccess,UpdateOnly,ReadOnly")]
    public IQueryable<Location> GetLocations()
    {
        return db.ActiveLocations;
    }
}
```

The api controller in [this Azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-oauth2-appidentity/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs) seems to be showing how to serve up different content based on identifying if it’s `user_impersonation` or not.

---

*EDIT:* I think [this tutorial from docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) may have the key to what I'm missing

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found this article finally that gets at what I’m needing to accomplish…
http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/

Basically in my appRoles node of my app registration’s Manifest.. there are 2 types of roles I can define, one for users and one for applications.. I think this is the route I need to go down
Then I can use the [Authorize(Roles=….)] as usual

Answer (score 0):

---

### ** THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER **

Ok, I think [after reading this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal), I learned that apps, (not the AD registration, but the actual Web App Resource) can have RBAC “built-in” roles assigned to them.

I’ve made this role assignment at the resource level (shown in the screenshot), but I think I can apply this at a more broad level, too

So, I’m hoping I can just add the “Reader” role to my [Authorize] roles list
[image: azure portal walkthough]